# get facebook likes count with feeds

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get my me/home timeline, and that is working fine, but I also want all the likes per feed, but it is not working.  I call the timeline through a function, so I can call the same function for my timeline or the last actions id did on fb, etc.

This is the function:

```
getRecentPosts('/me/home','feeds6');
```

When I call this:

```
getRecentPosts('/me/home?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(1)','feeds6');
```

It gives me undefined.
I try to call it like this:

```
response.data[x].total_count
```

I also tried `likes.summary.total_count` and `summary.total_count`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want feeds why are you querying `/me/home` instead of `/me/feed`?

Comment: yeah ok maybe i explain it wrong i ment that i want my timeline with the likes

Comment: Well obviously the total count can be get, but your question is not clear not me

Comment: Because i search google and there they say if you put this ?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(1) in the method or what its name is then you get the total_count of the likes and if i try this in the graph explorer it works it gives the total_count back so why cant it be get.if so why does it show up in the graph explorer...And the question is i want my timeline on my webpages and i want the total likes with every post.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be of format-

```
{
  "data": [
     {
       "id": "1111111111_2222222222", 
       "created_time": "2014-03-27T19:33:21+0000", 
       "likes": {
         "data": [
            {
              "id": "123456789564", 
              "name": "XXXXXX YYYYYY"
            }
         ], 
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "after": "MTAwMDAwNDA0NDE2NTg2", 
               "before": "MTAwMDAwNDA0NDE2NTg2"
            },  
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/123213123213_1231234434/likes?limit=1&summary=1&after=MTAwMDAwNDA0NDE2NTg2"
         }, 
         "summary": {
            "total_count": 113
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

So, to fetch the total count you should try-

```
if(response.data[x].summary !== undefined && response[x].data[x].summary.total_count !== undefined){
    count = response[x].data[x].summary.total_count;
}
else{
     count = 0;
}
```

Also try to log the complete `response` object to see its contents.

Comment: Then i get this error message in chrome Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_count' of undefined in all.js

Comment: This is because  you'll not get this `summary` for all the posts. Please check the complete list of posts you'll find this somewhere. Also did you log the complete `response` ?

Comment: The `summary`  field will exist in only those cases where `total_count` do exist for rest you'll get `undefined`. Also, try to print the complete `response` object

Comment: okay but it just stops when it has to read an object with the total count because it only gives me the first two posts.I also log the complete response object but it is alot what do i have to look for.

Comment: okay i try the code above and now it gives me at least a  zero but there are likes and it says 0

Comment: Are you sure there are likes? That's why I am saying to log the complete response. If you are using javascript just write- `console.log(response)`; and tell me the output

Comment: i get a lot of objects and when i click on it i see Object
data: Array[25]
paging: Object
__proto__: Object
 mijnfb.js:830

Comment: That means you are getting 25 posts from the timeline, Open them and see which post is having the likes (in the browser). Also you loop through all the array elements(25) and print their details and see if you can see total_count of any post or not

Comment: ok i dive into it i hope you will look later in (half hour or so) the evening if i have found something